# Processing CSV File using Python with data merge with complicated merging logic

Tags: python, file-processing

I have data in csv file. Here is the example

```
Sr# Inv_ID      IdType  IdValue          MIC

1   F000000EU6  CUSIP   29088TEST        null
2   F000000EU6  ISIN    US290886TEST     null
3   F000000EU6  SEDOL   23TEST1          XNAS
4   F000000EU6  TICKER  ETEST            XNAS
5   F000000EU6  SEDOL   23TEST2          XNGS
6   F000000EU6  TICKER  ETEST            XNGS
```

Investment Vehicle ID + MIC is a unique Key. After processing it should give me below result

```
Sr# SEDOL    MIC     ISIN            CUSIP      TICKER  Inv_ID
2   23TEST1  XNAS    US290886TEST    29088TEST  ETEST   F000000EU6
3   23TEST2  XNGS    US290886TEST    29088TEST  ETEST   F000000EU6
```

Since Investment Vehicle ID + MIC is unique combination it should generate two rows mentioned above. However Sr#1 and #2 same Investment Vehicle ID but MIC is null it **should not** generate separate row but add ISIN and CUSIP to the existing records

I was thinking of reading file twice
#1 for IDTypes = SEDOL and TICKER and skip ISINs and CUSIPs.
Generate records with key Investment Vehicle ID + MIC
So in above case two records will be generated with two different keys --> F000000EU6XNAS AND F000000EU6XNGS
Next read the file with ISIN and CUSIP
Update the existing records which with keys start with F000000EU6 with ISIN and CUSIPs values
No Match then create separate records with ISIN and CUSIP
I am facing lot of performance issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can some one please check this?

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please paste the code and the data here not with the screenshot.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "kind of unique". Uniqueness is a binary condition - i.e., it either is unique or it isn't

Comment: Its unique - i have removed 'kind of'

Comment: I have removed image and use table.

Comment: FYI, if you place a line of three backquotes before and after your sample data it will be formatted literally, just like a block of code. That will make it more compact and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it in one run. Your question is not very clear or complete. I had to cut some corners for the following code to work:

- the vertical alignment and the empty line in the input CSV may or may not be present in the actual input file, I am now processing a preprocessed version with the `csv` module, but this could be made more efficient
- I couldn't figure out the logic behind the `Sr#` column in the output, so I just left it out
- I haven't profiled this on large datasets which you might have

Anyway, I hope the following is helpful:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import re
from collections import defaultdict

FILENAME_INPUT = "data.csv"
with open(FILENAME_INPUT, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

DELIMITER_REGEX = r"\s+"
processed_lines = (
    re.sub(DELIMITER_REGEX, ",", line.strip()) for line in lines if line.strip()
)

investments: dict[str, dict[str, str]] = defaultdict(dict)
inv_info: dict[str, dict[str, str]] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))

csv_reader = csv.DictReader(processed_lines)
for row in csv_reader:
    mic = row["MIC"]
    inv_id = row["Inv_ID"]
    if mic == "null":
        inv_info[inv_id][row["IdType"]] = row["IdValue"]
        continue

    key = inv_id + mic
    investments[key]["MIC"] = mic
    investments[key]["Inv_ID"] = inv_id
    investments[key][row["IdType"]] = row["IdValue"]

FILENAME_OUTPUT = "output.csv"
with open(FILENAME_OUTPUT, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
        file, fieldnames=("SEDOL", "MIC", "ISIN", "CUSIP", "TICKER", "Inv_ID")
    )
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for investement in investments.values():
        investement["ISIN"] = inv_info[investement["Inv_ID"]]["ISIN"]
        investement["CUSIP"] = inv_info[investement["Inv_ID"]]["CUSIP"]
        csv_writer.writerow(investement)
```

The clue is that on scanning the file, you either store data for an investment at a specific (`investments`) or more generic (`inv_info`) level and just before writing collect all relevant data for a line.

(I only just now realise that I was assuming that 'inv' stands for 'investment', but probably 'inventory' makes more sense? :-D)

Comment: Gave ne below error - trying to find out.
inv_id = row["Inv_ID"]
             ~~~^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'Inv_ID'

Comment: that probably means your input file does not have a column titled (exactly) "Inv_ID"

Comment: Thanks This was a great help. However What I have seen in my case is I already have ```security_dict = {'F000000EU6XNAS' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST', 'XNAS'] , 'F000000EU6XNGS' : ['23TEST2','ETEST','XNGS'], 'F000000EU6' : '23TEST5'}``` Is there any way that I can convert it to ```security_dict_op = {'F000000EU6XNAS' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST', 'XNAS','23TEST5'] , 'F000000EU6XNGS' : ['23TEST2','ETEST','XNGS','23TEST5']}```